# React-bootstrap FormControl Select placeholder

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Trying to set up a control for a select field but even with `placeholder` set it still always auto selects the first item in the list.

It looks like this...

```
export function renderSelector({input, label, placeholder, meta:{touched, warning, error}, title, mandatory, fieldValues, fieldItemKeyFunc, fieldItemLabelFunc, props}) {


 const mappedData = fieldValues.map(v => ({Id: fieldItemKeyFunc(v), Name: fieldItemLabelFunc(v)}));
    let custom = props || {};
    return (
        <FormGroup controlId={input.name} validationState={touched && error ? 'error' : null}>
            <Col xs={12}>
                {renderLabel(title, label, mandatory)}
            </Col>
            <Col xs={12}>
                <FormControl componentClass="select" placeholder={placeholder} name={input.name} {...input} {...custom}>
                    {
                        mappedData.map((item, index) => {
                            return (
                                <option key={index} value={item.Id}>{item.Name}</option>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </FormControl>
                <FormControl.Feedback/>
                {renderErrBlock(touched, warning, error)}
            </Col>
        </FormGroup>
    );
```

}

When this renders the selector always starts with the first item selected, instead of the placeholder. How can I fix this?? I tried just adding a default first option and adjusting the css, but for Accessibility that doesn't work that well because the contrast levels

Answer (score 6):

A bit late, but check if adding this option helps you:

```
<option key='blankChoice' hidden value />
```

Make sure to check the form value to a blank choice as well:

```
<Form.Control
    value=''
>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

Add a

```
<option disabled value={-1} key={-1}>
```

, and set your

```
<FormControl value={-1} ...
```

for a similar effect.

Comment: This option sucks hard, but seems that this is the only way

Answer (score 2):

Just dropping a late answer, in case someone finds this useful.

React Bootstrap's Form `as='select'` doesn't seem to allow `placeholder` out of the box. Adding a blank value to `Form.Control` would render the input useless. Adding an extra `option` above `mappedData.map()`, as follows would work:

```
<option key = 'blankChoice' hidden value> --Your placeholder text-- </option>
```

Comment: Just as stated in the previous answer ^^